# Multilingual Storyboard English to Persian(Iran)

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, storyboard

I am working on VOIP application. My base storyboard is in english language. I used multiplier constraint for leading, trailing, height, width, top, bottom.... for all so that UI can work for all devices according to their screen size.

It is working for the english but I have to convert it for Persian(Iran) language as well. I added Persian Storyboard by clicking on Localization and converted all the text in Persian. When I changed my device language english to Persian and launch the app text changed according to device language but UI layout not displaying properly due to multiplier constraint.

**Layout in english language:**

[image: This is my UI in base (english) language]

**Layout in persian language:**

And it spoils entire UI when I change the device language to Persian.

[image: UI after language changed to Persian]

this is the way how i am giving constraint

[image: Constraints are implemented as]

So please help me how I can set the UI layout if language is R to L (Persian)

Comment: Looks like its layout issue, show your view with added constraint.

Comment: Show your login viewcontroller constaints from storyboard

Comment: @BhavinRamani i have added how i am giving constraint

Comment: @RahulPatel i have added how i am giving constraint

Comment: it seems you have problem with the container view not edit text or labels!